# Always block instead of assign, simulated in FPGA

Tags: verilog, fpga

I am trying to code and synthesize in Verilog. Sometimes I am still getting confused with using Verilog as a typical C like programming language, I am trying to understand if there will be a difference between 2 different codes:

```
always @ (a1,a0,b1,b0)
begin
case ({a1,a0,b1,b0})
                 4'b0000 : s= 7'b1110111 ;
                 4'b0001 : s= 7'b1110111  ;
                  ....
                  ....
                 4'b1110 : s= 7'b0101111  ; 
                 4'b1111 : s= 7'b1111010 ;
                 endcase


    end
```

and

using the above code logic with assign, instead of always block.

Will the above code generate a latch? In which case would it generate a latch? Will there be any delay difference between using the 2 codes?

PS we are trying to create a 2bit binary multiplier, which outputs to a 7 segm display.
Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Latches are generated when one or more paths through a conditional statement are unassigned. For example:

```
reg [1:0] a;
reg b;
always@(*)
case (a)
    0: b=0;
    1: b=0;
    2: b=1;
endcase
```

would generate a latch, because I did not cover the a=3 case. You can avoid this by either explicitly covering each case (like it appears you have done) or by using the `default` case.

For assign statements, it depends on how you format them, but you're significantly less likely to accidentally infer a latch. For example, if you you the ternary operation (i.e. `assign b = a? 1:0;`) both halves of the `if` are inferred.

As for delay, case vs. assign should create the same netlist, so they should produce similar or identical results, provided they're logically identical.

*(As a side note, it's good practice to use `always@(*)`, rather than `always @ (a1,a0,b1,b0)`; The synthesis tool can figure out the correct sensitivity list.)*

Comment: Alright. Seems pretty reasonable. Thank you for your time :). I was worried that its bad practice to use always for sequential logic, but  as I was browsing though verilog documentation, its pretty standard, right?

Comment: I assume you meant combinational logic (which yours is), not sequential? I find always blocks to be more readable for anything more complex than an if/else, with the same functionality. The latest Verilog/SystemVerilog standard even includes a new `always_comb` specifically for doing combinational logic.

Comment: `assign` is fine for simple one-liner assignments and tri-state drivers. Beyond that `always @*`/`always_comb` are preferred for combinational logic. Sequential is logic is clocked triggered (ex: `always @(posedge clk)`)

Comment: @wilcroft yes, i couldnt edit my comment fast enough. I meant combinational logic.